# IBM websphere MQ posting query

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a way to post messages to Messaging destination queue without the MQ client?

We are planning to move the existing application to Enterprise Message Broker . The existing application has MQ Manager running in our local host. And We just use MQ jar files in Java to open socket and post the messages.  Am not sure MQ client is used at all ?

If we use MQ client am not sure what all I need to change in my application. Please clear my doubts.

Below is the code we use?  Are we using Client mode or Bindings mode? 
Will this same code work for client connection ??

```
er.WriteEntry(String.valueOf(paramMqConfig.getmqQmgr()));
  com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.hostname = paramMqConfig.getmqServer();
  com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.channel = paramMqConfig.getmqChannel();
  com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.port = paramMqConfig.getQMgrport();
  qMgr = new MQQueueManager(paramMqConfig.getmqQmgr());
  queue = qMgr.accessQueue(paramMqConfig.getmqQueue(), i, "", "", "");
  MQMessage localMQMessage = new MQMessage();
  format = "MQSTR   ";
  messageType = 8;
  com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions localMQPutMessageOptions = new com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions();
  localMQMessage.clearMessage();
  localMQMessage.writeString(paramString);
  queue.put(localMQMessage, localMQPutMessageOptions);
  str = "OK";
```

Comment: What version of MQ jar files are you using?  You can find this in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in any of the com.ibm jar files.  If you are using v8 or later IBM will fully support you having only the jar files bundled with your application.  In versions prior to v8 this worked but was not supported.  In short if you have a java application that uses the IBM jar files to connect to MQ it is not using any part of the full client install.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc. Now what I would need to change in my java application to use the mqclient to post the XML?

Comment: @JoshMc  - I have added sample code.

Comment: Because you are specifying `hostname`, `channel`, and `port`, this would be a Client mode connection.  You should be able to run that on separate server from the MQ Queue Manager as long as you have the client jar files in place.  If you do not have any version requirements then I would suggest you go with 9.0.0.1, it will have the longest support life and can connect to Queue managers running older versions with out issue.  I will put this info in a answer if it helped you.